# youtube on safari doesn't auto sign in

Tags: safari, login, youtube, google

I'm signed into my google account on safari, and things like gmail work fine. However, every time I go to youtube, it appears signed out, and when I click "sign in", it signs in without asking for password.'

So it's not really signed out, but just needs me to click the button, and then it shows me my actual logged-in homepage with all my personalized recommended videos, etc.

What gives? I'm expecting it to go directly to my logged-in page when I navigate to youtube, not require me to click "sign-in".

I'm using Monterey with 14 inch m1 pro. no extensions in safari, mostly default settings.

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution for it. Go to safari preferences> privacy> uncheck prevent cross site tracking. That's it